# How to configure reverse proxy/loadbalancer for custom routing

Tags: apache2, scalability, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

Suppose I have 3 webservers behind a reverse proxy/loadbalancer. Currently I use Apache 2 but don't mind switching.

Those webservers are not equal. They have different sets of local data meaning that different kinds of requests will be handled more efficiently on specific webserver.

I want to plug some custom routing logic into my loadbalancer, that would on start of a new session select a webserver for it, then tie that session to that node until it breaks down (sticky session).

For example: a new user comes to the webapp, load balancer runs my custom code somehow, this code finds out information about that user and makes a conclusion that this user should be handled on node1. The balancer proxies that user to node1 and sticks it to it. When another user comes, custom routing logic suggests node3, to which loadbalancer then proxies this user.

Is it possible to do with Apache 2? If not, what proxy/loadbalancer would give me that ability?

Thank you.

Comment: You'd get better help over at Server Fault. :)

Comment: @artemb, did you manage to achieve what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Apache [mode_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) has [stickyness](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#stickyness_implementation) if you want to stay on apache.

Otherwise, have a look at [Haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.3/doc/haproxy-en.txt). The first line of the abstract states: "route HTTP requests depending on statically assigned cookies ;"
You just have to set a cookie to know which backend you want the user to be stuck to.

Comment: The question was about custom routing (routing the _first_ request to a particular node), not about stickyness (routing _subsequent_ requests to the same node as the first one).